# This MID is not available on our staging environment in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i am try to integrate paytm payment gateway in Flutter but it's work well in stagging but when i am move stagging to production envirenment that show me error. This MID is not available on our staging environment.

dependencies:
  paytm: ^1.0.0

import 'package:paytm/paytm.dart';

void generateCheckSum() async {

var url ='https://us-central1-mrdishant-4819c.cloudfunctions.net/generateCheckSum';

```
String orderId = tnxidController.text;

//Please use your parameters here
//CHANNEL_ID etc provided to you by paytm

final response = await http.post(url, headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}, body: {
  "mid": "------------------",
  "CHANNEL_ID": "WAP",
  'INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID': 'Retail',
  'WEBSITE': 'APPSTAGING',
  'PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY': '--------------',
  'TXN_AMOUNT': amountController.text,
  'ORDER_ID': orderId,
  'CUST_ID': Constant.SUPERID,
});

String callBackUrl ='https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=' + orderId;

print("Response :" + response.body);

var paytmResponse = Paytm.startPaytmPayment(
    true,
    "---------------------",
    orderId,
    Constant.SUPERID,
    "WAP",
    amountController.text,
    'APPSTAGING',
    callBackUrl,
    'Retail',
    response.body);

paytmResponse.then((value) {
  setState(() {
    payment_response = value.toString();
  });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are still using the staging `callBackUrl`, the staging `WEBSITE` and the staging `INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID`. You should change those to their production values, for `callBackUrl` it starts with `https://securegw.paytm.in`